# aligning a div Horizontal & Vertical using CSS in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, responsive-design

I am trying to algn a div  in Horizontal & Vertical way using CSS. This approach is working on Chrome, but doesn't work in Safari.

```
.in-middle { min-height: 100%; min-height: 100vh; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column; }
```

Code Working: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gjrwndye/1/

Is there any suggestions how can I improve it to make it working on safari as well .

Answer (score 4):

Use browser prefixes.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gkh6gz3/

```
display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
```

You can check if you need to use prefixes using [Should I Prefix](http://shouldiprefix.com/).

You can automatically prefix your CSS using [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer).